# Delete image from Database using PHP (wordpress) along with it's record in DB

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress

I have this code that deletes a student record from the database, it deletes the student information as well as where an image is stored on the server however, I also want it to delete the image file itself, not just the record. How can I do this.

This code is where the user clicks to delete the student.

```
    <a href="javascript:void();" onclick="deleteItem
    (<?php echo $student_row->id;?>,<?php echo $_REQUEST['regNumber'];?>,
    <?php echo $student_row->id;?>,'parent')">Delete</a>
```

This code is the JS code referenced above:

```
function deleteItem(registration_number,parent_id,id,type)
{
  var parent_id = "<?php echo $_REQUEST['regNumber'];?>";
  var url_pass="<?php echo get_site_url();?>/student-delete/?
  regNoIndivid="+registration_number+
  "&parentId="+parent_id+"&id="+id+"&type="+type;
  if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
    window.location.href = url_pass;
  }
  return false;
}
```

This is from student-delete:

```
if($_REQUEST['type'] == "teacher")
{
    $where=array("id"=>$_REQUEST['id']);
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($where);echo "</pre>";
    //$delete_row=$wpdb->delete('wp_new_student_user', $where);
    $delete_row = $wpdb->query('DELETE FROM wp_new_student_user WHERE id 
    ='.$_REQUEST['id']);
    $wpdb->show_errors();

    if($delete_row)
    {
        $url_location=get_site_url()."/my-account-teacher/?
        regNumber=".$_REQUEST['parentId']."&type=tea&back_list=yes";
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href="<?php echo $url_location;?>";
        </script>
        <?php 
    }
}
elseif ($_REQUEST['type'] == "parent") {
    $where=array("id"=>$_REQUEST['id']);
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($where);echo "</pre>";
    //$delete_row=$wpdb->delete('wp_new_student_user', $where);
    $delete_row = $wpdb->query('DELETE FROM wp_new_student_user WHERE id 
    ='.$_REQUEST['id']);
    $wpdb->show_errors();

    if($delete_row)
    {
        $url_location=get_site_url()."/my-account-parent/?
        regNumber=".$_REQUEST['parentId']."&type=par&back_list=yes";
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href="<?php echo $url_location;?>";
        </script>
        <?php 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use PHP UNLINK function to delete the file

```
if($delete_row)
    {
        unlink(Path to the file);

    }
```

Comment: So it would be:

if($delete_row)
{
 $some_variable_store_file_path= Get path from db using sql query;
      unlink($some_variable_store_file_path);

}